# How to connect QSpinBox with current frame number of a Video [i.e cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)];?

Tags: c++, qt, video

In my project, from a method, I am getting current frame number of a Video from `cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)`while it is playing, which is continuously increasing.

I am trying to connect this with a `QSpinBox`, so that the current value of `QSpinbox` will be changed with the increasing number of current frame number by `setValue(int)` and vice versa, the current frame number will also be changed with `QSpinBox::valueChanged(int)`.

I have already created a `signal` in `mainWindow.h`

```
signals:
void sendCurrentFrame(int&);
```

Then I tried to emit this from this method

```
cap >> frame;        
int CurrentFrame=cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);
int TotalFrame=cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
ui->spinBox->setMaximum(TotalFrame);                           
emit sendCurrentFrame(CurrentFrame);
```

Then I tried to connect this with `QSpinBox`

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(sendCurrentFrame(int&)),ui->spinBox,SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

But unfortunately, when the video is playing the `QSpinBox` is not changing it's value, where it sets the maximum value perfectly by `setMaximum(int)`.

I am not displaying the video by `QMediaPlayer`, so connecting `QMediaPlayer` with `QSpinBox` is no more possible.

Can anyone share any idea if I have done any logical mistake?
I really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show your code please

Comment: You don't need `int&` for sending the `int` via the signal. Just send `int`.

Comment: Still I am a bit confused. Can you please write 2 lines example code? I am not understanding if I don't use `int&` how can I send a signal. @AlexanderVX

Comment: Yes sure, you can find the code [here](https://github.com/ashraful100/VideoPlay). I would really appreciate your help. @eyllanesc

Comment: Change `void sendCurrentFrame(int&);` to `void sendCurrentFrame(int);` and `connect(this, SIGNAL(sendCurrentFrame(int&)),ui->spinBox,SLOT(setValue(int)));` to `connect(this, SIGNAL(sendCurrentFrame(int)),ui->spinBox,SLOT(setValue(int)));`

Comment: When a signal is sent, the slot and signal must have the same parameters, and it is preferable to pass the variables by value than by reference.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it is working fine.Can you give one more idea? I also want to get data from the `QSpinBox`. I mean when the `QSpinBox` is changed the video frame will also be changed according to `QSpinBox` data. Thanks again. @eyllanesc